# Actionsheet handle event function does not executes on 1st click in Ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to implement sorting a data on basis of some attributes like name,complete,incomplete etc in an ionic3 application. I have implemented `Actionsheet` for this but it does not seems to work on first click.However this works on later clicks.below is the code of the `.ts` file for reference.

```
  sort(property){
    this.isDesc = !this.isDesc; //change the direction    
    this.column = property;
    let direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;

    this.dataList.sort(function(a, b){

      console.log(a);

        if(a[property] < b[property]){
            return -1 * direction;
        }
        else if( a[property] > b[property]){
            return 1 * direction;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    });

    console.log(this.dataList);
  };

  createactions(){
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
    title: 'Action Sheet Title',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Sort By Completed',
            handler: () => {
                this.sort('complete');
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Sort By Incomplete',
            handler: () => {
                this.sort('incomplete');
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Sort By Name',
            handler: () => {
               this.sort('VillageName');
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Hide',
            handler: () => {
                let navTransition = actionSheet.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        }
      ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();    
  }
```

As requested the code for the calling of `createactions()` is as follows

```
<ion-fab right bottom>
  <button ion-fab (click)="createactions()">
    <ion-icon name="stats"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-fab>
```

Unable to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not be dismissing the action sheet yourself. If you simply add the property `role` to the object with the hide `text` property it will act as a cancel button.

```
{
     text: 'Hide',
     role: 'cancel'
     handler: () => {
          let navTransition = actionSheet.dismiss();
          return false;
     }
}
```

**Edit**: I accidentally posted an answer, but it does not provide a solution to your problem. Can you please show us more information? How are you calling the `createactions` method